# How to create a Ajax form with Add , Remove buttons for multi value field form without submit button in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Hi I would like to create a custom Drupal form where there is a textfiled in which I input some data and it gets saved in variable table.

My requirement is the form should only contain `Add` , `Remove` and `Add More` button to add additional textfiled .

When the textfiled is empty it should show Add button adjacent to textfiled (when inputting data and clicking Add button it should save data in variable table ) ,when the textfiled is not empty it should show remove button adjacent to textfiled (when clicking Remove button it should remove data in variable table )

Clicking `Add More` button needs to create a empty textfiled with `Add` button adjacent to it.

All this need to happen without page reload.

I was able to achieve the task with `Add` , `Remove` , `Add More` and `Submit` Buttons.

I looked into the available resources and example modules but cant find helpful resource.

Can any one help me to modify the code so that the `Submit` Button can be removed.

**My Code is as follows**:

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu() {

    $items = array();

    $items['admin/mymodule'] = array(
        'title' => t('Example form'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('mymodule_ajax_example_add_more'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

    return $items;
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more($form, &$form_state) {

  $mymodule_ajax_events = variable_get('mymodule_ajax_example_content', array());
  $mymodule_ajax_events_count = count($mymodule_ajax_events);

  if ($mymodule_ajax_events_count == 0) {
    $mymodule_ajax_events_count = 1;
  }

  $form = array();
  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $form['mymodule_ajax_events'] = [
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#weight' => 80,
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    // Set up the wrapper so that AJAX will be able to replace the fieldset.
    '#prefix' => '<div id="js-ajax-elements-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];
  $form_state['field_deltas'] = isset($form_state['field_deltas']) ? $form_state['field_deltas'] : range(0, $mymodule_ajax_events_count-1);

  $field_count = $form_state['field_deltas'];
  foreach ($field_count as $delta) {
    $form['mymodule_ajax_events'][$delta] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['container-inline'],
      ],
      '#tree' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['mymodule_ajax_events'][$delta]['event_url'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Event URL' . ($delta + 1)),
      '#size' => 40,
      '#default_value' => (isset($mymodule_ajax_events[$delta])) ? $mymodule_ajax_events[$delta] : '',
    ];

    $form['mymodule_ajax_events'][$delta]['remove_event_url'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Remove'),
      '#submit' => ['mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_remove'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_remove_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'js-ajax-elements-wrapper',
      ],
      '#weight' => 50,
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['button-small'],
      ],
      '#name' => 'remove_event_url_' . $delta,
    );
  }

  $form['mymodule_ajax_events']['add_event_url'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add one more'),
    '#submit' => ['mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_add_one'],
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_add_one_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'js-ajax-elements-wrapper',
    ],
    '#weight' => 1,
  );
    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#weight' => 100,
  );

  return $form;
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_remove($form, &$form_state) {
  $delta_remove = $form_state['triggering_element']['#parents'][1];
  $k = array_search($delta_remove, $form_state['field_deltas']);
  unset($form_state['field_deltas'][$k]);

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  drupal_get_messages();
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_remove_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['mymodule_ajax_events'];
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_add_one($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['field_deltas'][] = count($form_state['field_deltas']) > 0 ? max($form_state['field_deltas']) + 1 : 0;
  //mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_validate();
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  // drupal_get_messages();
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_add_one_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['mymodule_ajax_events'];
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_validate($form, $form_state) {
    dpm($form_state);
  foreach ($form_state['values']['mymodule_ajax_events'] as $key => $item) {
      //dpm($item);
      dpm($item['event_url']);
   if (!empty($item['event_url'])) {
      if (!preg_match('/https:\/\/example.com.*/i', $item['event_url'])) {
        form_set_error("mymodule_ajax_events][$key][event_url", 'Enter a valid Event URL.' . ($key + 1));
        //
      }else{
       drupal_set_message('URL ' . ($key + 1) . ' Created' );
   }
   }
 }
}

function mymodule_ajax_example_add_more_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $events_content = array();
  $events_count = 0;
  foreach ($form_state['values']['mymodule_ajax_events'] as $key => $item) {
    if (!empty($item['event_url'])) {
      $events_content[] = $item['event_url'];
      $events_count++;
   }
 }
  variable_set('mymodule_ajax_example_content', $events_content);
  variable_set('mymodule_ajax_example_count', $events_count);
}
```

Comment: How about using webform module and hooking it if needed. You'll get much more functionality with much less work.

Comment: Can you please be little more specific? I want those values to be stored in database, which I will retrieve and use them for later on.

Comment: Webform module is already storing results to database, can send notification emails and much more. And even more, you can use form hook functions to additionally tweak web forms created by this module, i.e. add custom action handler to do your work when form is submitted.